# How to multi select MIME type for Android PhotoPicker

Tags: android, photo-picker

I'd like to use Android PhotoPicker, then I want multi MIME type that can JPEG, PNG but can only single MIME type, how can I get it?

```kotlin
// Launch the photo picker and let the user choose only images/videos of a
// specific MIME type, such as GIFs.
val mimeType = "image/gif"
pickMedia.launch(PickVisualMediaRequest(PickVisualMedia.SingleMimeType(mimeType)))
```

https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/photopicker

Comment: Have you tried with ```"image/*"```?

Comment: @jayeshgurudayalani That available but I want just JPEG and PNG type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a subclass of PickVisualMedia as follows:

```kotlin
class PickImage : PickVisualMedia() {
    override fun createIntent(context: Context, input: PickVisualMediaRequest): Intent {
        val intent = super.createIntent(context, input)
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, arrayOf("image/jpeg", "image/png"))
        return intent
    }
}

interface Launcher {
    fun launch()
}

@Composable
fun rememberPickImageLauncherForActivityResult(onResult: (Uri?) -> Unit): Launcher {
    val launcher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(contract = PickImage(), onResult = onResult)
    return object : Launcher {
        override fun launch() {
            launcher.launch(PickVisualMediaRequest(PickVisualMedia.SingleMimeType("*/*")))
        }
    }
}

val launcher = rememberPickImageLauncherForActivityResult { uri ->
  // read data from the uri
}

launcher.launch()
```

According to the following document, when using EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, the MIME type should be set to "*/*". That's the reason for setting SingleMimeType to "*/*".

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common

> EXTRA_MIME_TYPES
>
> An array of MIME types corresponding to the types of files your app is requesting. When you use this extra, you must set the primary MIME type in setType() to "*/*".

Comment: What is the Launcher?